# What is verb tense consistency?

Tags: tenses, sense-verbs, bare-infinitive, predicate-frames

"To his great astonishment and mortification, **Sticky saw his parents begin trying less and less to find him,** instead devoting their time and energy toward the proper disposal of their newfound riches"

So I stumbled upon this sentence and the part which usually confuses is keeping the consistency of the tenses and my english teacher also points it out in my essays but tries in vain explaining it to me .

So the sentence sounds perfect to me, but still is there a reason against -" Sticky saw his parents **began** trying less and less to find"- being incorrect.
Will be much obliged if someone can get me over with this.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The wording that you say you think it should be ***is*** the wording that's used in the quote.

Comment: That sentence has exactly one tensed verb. What's to stay consistent with?

Comment: @tchrist i have done the corrections

Comment: Oh, now I see. You've mixed up *saw them begin* with *saw that they began*.

Comment: The actual cited context is a bit complex for the verb usage under consideration. But so far as I can see it's exactly the same as *I saw John **leave*** (where that final highlighted verb is an ***infinitive***). In principle the past participle *could* be used there *(I saw John **left**)*, but we'd usually include the "optional" subordinating conjunction - *I saw **that** John **left***. The same applies with the specific example cited above - *Sticky saw **that** his parents **began** trying less...* Alternatively, *Sticky saw [that] his parents **were beginning to try** less...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers well I don't actually  understand why the original text is correct (and also aren't past participles used with have/had ,so how  is "I saw John left ' correct)

Comment: @MUMBAS: *I saw John left* is a syntactically valid but fairly unusual shortening of *I saw **that** John left, I saw that John **did in fact leave**, I saw **the act of John leaving***. But like I say, this would be unusual phrasing that you probably won't need to know at this stage in your learning process. In the construction ***I saw [subject] [verb]***, the verb is usually an infinitive *(I saw John **leave**)* unless you specifically want to reference what you saw as a continuous act taking place over time *(I saw John **leaving**)*. That's really all you need here, I think.

Comment: ...it might be pouring petrol on the flames, but I'll just add that *in principle*, your text could have had *Sticky saw [that] his parents **had begun** trying...* or *...saw his parents **beginning to try...*** There are many ways we can deliberately introduce more complex verb forms without necessarily affecting the basic meaning, but "Simplest is usually best", so focus on the ***infinitive*** here because it's the easiest and most flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verb tense consistency is about using the same tenses to refer to one time period within a clause. In your sentence, this isn't an issue. The time is all in the past as determined by the verb 'saw'.

Here's a simple instance of non-consistent tenses where the middle verb is in the present while the first and last use the simple past tense:

> *X bought a coffee, sits down, and opened her laptop.

To make the tenses consistent you could correct to

> X bought a coffee, sat down and opened her laptop.

or

> X buys a coffee sits down and opens her laptop.

But the verb forms in your sample sentence are fine.

> Sticky saw his parents begin trying less and less to find him

'Begin' is not a tense marker here. The sentence follows a [pattern](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing) where an *infinitive (or -ing) verb form* can follow the object of some verbs of perception: e.g.

> I saw him fall.
>   I heard her turn(ing) the key in the lock.
>   She watched him leave.
>   Sticky saw his parents begin (...)

Comment: @S Conroy and are these type of questions called something in particular in the english language.

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of anything more specific than what I've written above. In books for English language learners, it is sometimes discussed under the simple heading of sentence patterns (or syntax), but there are so many different sentence patterns and all languages have their own  pattern rules so, as I say, very general. Perhaps someone else can help.